# Gateway IP for access points

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm currently struggling to get a series of wireless APs. But there isn't a continuous connection for the Wireless connection.

There is a main router which provides the initial Network Name with an IP 192.168.2.1. There are then two APs which are connect to the network via the Network over Power extenders. The APs have static IPs assigned: 192.168.2.2, and 192.168.2.3.

Both currently have their Gateway IPs set to 0.0.0.0 but that doesn't seem to work. I've read up a few articles that mention that you need to set the Gateway IP to the IP of the main router (192.168.2.1) but if I do that, then devices can't connect to the WiFi generated by the AP. They are on seperate channels; main - 6, APs - 7 + 8 and have been set to broadcast the Network Name. What am I doing wrong to prevent a seemless wireless setup?

Edit:

Both Access points are model TL-WA901N set to access point mode

Comment: What kind of APs? Are they really in bridge (AP) mode, and not accidentally set to router mode? For true APs (bridges), the gateway parameter wouldn't have any effect on connected devices.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the models of devices.

Comment: Have you used the exact procedure as in the article
[How to configure TL-WA701ND V2, TL-WA801ND V2, TL-WA901ND V3 or TL-WA7210N as a repeater?](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/492/) Why have you used low IP addresses such as 192.168.2.2 and 192.168.2.3 and how did you ensure no conflicts? Where did you specify a gateway and what for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing much too much, which leads me suppose that you have not setup
correctly the two TL-WA901N as access-points.

See the article
[How to configure TL-WA701ND V2, TL-WA801ND V2, TL-WA901ND V3 or TL-WA7210N as a repeater?](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/492/)
for the exact steps with screenshots.

To resume the steps:

- Log into the TP-Link **Quick Setup** page and click Next
- Choose the Operation mode **Repeater (Range Extender)**, and click Next
- Select **Universal Repeater** as the **Repeater Mode** and click **Survey**
- Find in the list the root router’s SSID and click **Connect**
- Confirm the Wireless security mode and input the Wireless Password of
  the root router, then click Next
- Make sure the DHCP Server is disabled and click Next
- Ensure the Repeater’s IP address is in the same IP segment as the
  root router and avoid IP conflicts
- Reboot the router.